Is there a way to systematically generate a large file with NodeJS?
I am trying to create a "randomly" generated large file (4GB+) for testing purposes. The goal is to have the file containing "random" data such that when being compressed, it won't get compressed that much... but I need to generate the same "random" file across different platforms (ex: Linux, Windows, etc).
To have it cross-platform, I am thinking of using NodeJS since I already have it installed/running via my Dockerfile for each platform... but I am not sure how to reliably recreate such a large file. I don't want to copy the file into my image, because the footprint would be huge.
In addition, I couldn't just write like "1234567890" millions of times into the file either, as it would still get compressed significantly.
How would you tackle this?

Use a simple RNG, for instance RC4. Given the same seed (i.e. key) it will produce the same stream of bytes for as long as you want it to.
